# Jquery return to previous state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with the .click function of jquery. I want to some data and when I press a button It should change the html. The thing is, after changing the html, it loop back to the previous state. How can I stop that?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){       
    $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=9c7ff6051e83a1f812dc1207c4afe906&units=metric', function(asd){
     console.log('stage 1')              
             $("#button").click(function(){
                    console.log('stage 2')                  
                    $("#temp").text("la temperatura actual es: "+ asd.main.temp + " °C");
                    $("#temp-min").text("la temperatura minima es: " + asd.main.temp_min + " °C");
                    $("#temp-max").text("la temperatura maxima es: " + asd.main.temp_max + " °C");
                    $("#description").text("El cielo esta: " + asd.weather.main);
                    $("#wind").text("La velocidad del viento es de: " + asd.wind.speed + " Km/h");
                    $("#rain").text("La probabilidad de lluvia es de: ")
                    console.log('stage 3')                      
                    });
    });             
});
```

To make it more clear. I'm able to reach 'stage 3' but then it return to 'stage 1'

Comment: Is `#button` an actual `<button>`? Does it have `type="button"`? If not, it will act as a submit button, which effectively reloads the page. I think that might be the effect you're seeing.

Comment: @David Hedlund Thanks, It was that